# how can I validate two ASP.NET pages have the same output HTML?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, refactoring, nunit, legacy-code

I am working on legacy code for an ASP.NET website, and I want to refactor.

I've come to the conclusion that the easiest way to test for breaks is to compare the final HTML with the old page, especially since there is so much dependency to the UI anyway. (Please criticize if this is a bad approach)

The page is dynamically created from the query string so I will need to generate tests with all the different combinations.

How can I run this test, ideally I would also like to integrate it into a tool such as NUnit, can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some options in Visual Studio if you have the Tester edition or the ultimate edition, and [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) could be another option.

With respect to testing UI and you are still in webforms, it's always pretty complicated, so depending on your scenarios, some things are easy to test in code (before the UI) and others can just be looked at, until the end with your HTML rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Add even a single container control like a Panel would totally break your logic as this changes the ClientIDs generated for legacy asp.net.

You are bound to get too many false positives, where the page isn't really broken.

Also, asp.net doesn't render anything that is set to `Visible` false. Unless your project has no code that is made visible on button clicks(PostBacks), you should not follow this approach. You would miss out any changes to the hidden sections.

User acceptance of a final page after refactoring, migration; is best done manually.
You can automate the testing of the data and business logic layers, but with legacy asp.net automating the UI testing seems like something that would take up too much time and yield little benefit.

Comment: 2 questions. 1) can I mimic a postback? 2) if I check only the relevant HTML, ie parse into valid XML with HTMLAgilityPack and check only sections with specific id, is this still a bad approach?

Comment: The problem is that the ids will change. The approach is not bad. The time you may have to invest to get it right, does not seem worth it. This is subjective, depending on the size of your website.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across an interesting tool that seems to do this, called Approval Tests by Llewellyn Falco.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52YouQkd-f8